# How to best keep my controllers view agnostic?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, separation-of-concerns

I have the following code in a controller:

```
$this->viewdata->scripts = array(
    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js',
    'jstree/jquery.jstree-1.0-rc2.js',
    'jquery.hotkeys-0.8.js',
    'tags/index.js'
);

$this->viewdata->styles = array(
    'reset.css',
    'tags.css'
);
```

In my view I have a `foreach` to wrap each of the listed javascript/css files into the respective HTML tag. I'm using a master template/layout approach; I just populate any/all fields in the master template and I end up with my web page. So, it's good for me to have my javascript/css all set up in the controller so my `<script>`s and `<link>`s can be in the `<head>`, where they belong.

However, it dawned on me recently that the javascript and css do not belong in the controller because the view that's rendered is subject to change and may have very different javascript/css requirements.

I basically want to keep just one master template for maintainability but to also remove all reference to view/javascript/css from the controllers. What's out there to help me do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont use CI, but i regularly use Zend and Symfony. In both these frameworks there is some sort of asset helper you can call from the view to add css or js files to the stack. You then place a call to similar helper to output those files in your head. for example in symfony:

View:

```
<?php use_stylesheet('/css/mycss.css'); ?>
<?php use_stylesheet('/css/components.css'); ?>
<?php use_javascript('/js/site.js'); ?>
```

Layout:

```
<head>
  <?php include_javascripts(); ?>
  <?php include_stylesheets(); ?>
</head>
```

I would think something like this would be relatively easy to implement in CI if not present out of the box...

Answer (score 1):

I had a project that I did the same thing, albeit less eloquently.  I thought I would reduce the amount of information being sent to the client by "dynamically" loading js and css.  I used the controllers to define arrays of file names and loops in my views to include them.

I recall that there was only one js file I didn't end up including all the time.

You have to decide which of the following you believe more than the other.

1. js/css don't belong in the controllers
2. php doesn't belong in the view

It's a messy decision you have to just find your own way through.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you're probably not using cakePHP from that code sample, but! They have a great methodology of handling this problem. It's a parameter for "inline" styles, scripts, etc...

In your  tag, you have something such as:

```
<?= $scripts_for_layout ?>
<?= $styles_for_layout ?>
```

And in the view file itself, you have code like this:

```
<?php $this->Html->script('jquery', array('inline' => true)); ?>
```

So the actual view file renders, stores all of the scripts into some array somewhere, then renders the layout file (header, footer, what have you).

The layout file takes the arrays that were stored and renders then into the $scripts_for_layout variable.

Pretty genius and works great. I suggest doing something like this.

Reference: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1589/script

Comment: I've not done it quite like that but the principle is the same - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is your project or team actually large enough for SoC to be a concern? Or at least, one worth the time of asking this question and waiting for an answer? Do you expect your views and css / js files to change sometime later?

If your answer to these is yes, and it is worth modifying your design, then you can make your views include the css and js themselves. There will be a lot in common, so make views that just have the common css and js files in them, and include that view file in your other views. You don't need anything complicated here. Or at least, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your have the right approach in that you want all your global scripts and styles located within one controller.  And you are on the right path in thinking that you want the flexibility of being able to include specific scripts and styles to specific pages.

To achieve this, you can create a base controller and extending controllers.  Your base controller will contain all your global scripts and styles.  Your extending controllers will contain scripts and styles specific only to a certain page (or group of pages).

Check out the following link on creating a base controller:
http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY

Note that in CI2 that base controllers should be located in the */application/core/* directory.